# How to hide an alert based on an 'if' condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an alert that displays on a website, on specific days of the year.

My question is this: How can I hide that alert IF the date is not one of those days? I was thinking the below code would work, but it only delays the alert based on a condition in my code I can see, but I'm not sure how to work around that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   /* if (typeof window.sessionStorage != undefined) {
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem('mySessionVal')) { */
            $('<div />', {
                id   : "alertmsg",
                text :"",
                on   : {
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).slideUp(500);
                    }
                }
            }).appendTo('body').slideDown(1).delay(6000).slideToggle("fast");
            sessionStorage.setItem('mySessionVal', false);
            sessionStorage.setItem('storedWhen', (new Date()).getTime());

      var now = new Date();
      var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
      var month = now.getMonth();
      var date = now.getDate();
      var year = now.getFullYear();
      var msg;
      if (month == 0, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our January issue have now closed.";
      else if (month == 3, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our April issue have now closed.";
      else if (month == 6, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our July issue have now closed.";
      else if (month == 9, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our October issue have now closed.";
      else $('#alertmsg').hide();
      $('#alertmsg').text(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got `if (month == 0, date ==1)` from but it should be `if (month == 0 && date == 1)`. This should be the same for each of the `if`s

Answer (score 0):

Your last line after the if statement is

```
$('#alertmsg').text(msg);
```

Meaning that after you check for the month name regardless to the content of `msg` you are putting the text inside the div.

You can do something like this:

```
var now = new Date();
      var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
      var month = now.getMonth();
      var date = now.getDate();
      var year = now.getFullYear();
      var msg;
      if (month == 0, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our January issue have now closed.";
      else if (month == 3, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our April issue have now closed.";
      else if (month == 6, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our July issue have now closed.";
      else if (month == 9, date ==1) msg = "Submissions for our October issue have now closed.";

if(msg != '') {

 // append the div to body here and assign the msg into it
}
```

Comment: If the date does not fall on one of the above days, I don't need a message at all. Will appending the div hide it all together?

Comment: you will only append the div when msg has content, so if the date is not one of your if statement, msg will be empty and the div will not be created and appended to the body

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to learn JQuery, so I didn't have a good idea of how to solve the above issue, but I think I finally did! I just added the below code after my final IF statement.

```
else $('#alertmsg').removeAttr('id');
      $('#alertmsg').text(msg);
```